# How to navigate by posts loaded per json file

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/brWn6r4UvLnNY5gcFF2X?p=preview

For example I have a json file:

```
{
  "info": {
     "test1": "test",
     "teste2": "test"
  },

   "posts": [
      {
        "name": "lorem ipsum",
        "content": "sit amet lorem ipsum"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ipsum lorem",
        "content": "sit amet lorem ipsum"
      },
      {
        "name": "lorem ipsum",
        "content": "sit amet lorem ipsum"
      },
      {
        "name": "Sit amet",
        "content": "sit amet lorem ipsum"
      }
   ]
}
```

In my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $route, $routeParams, $filter) {
  $scope.name = 'Teste';

  $scope.getData = function(){
    $http.get('posts.json')
      .then(function(res){
          $scope.posts = res.data.posts;
          $scope.currentPost = $filter('filter')($scope.posts, {id: $routeParams.id})
          //console.log(res.data.posts);
        });
  };
  //setInterval($scope.getData, 1000);
  $scope.getData();
});

// Routes
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
   .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
  })
  .when('/posts/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'post.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

});
```

In my Home view:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
<a href="./#/posts/{{ post.id  }}">
  <h3>{{ post.name  }}</h3>
  <h5>=> {{ post.content  }}</h5>
</a>
</div>
```

And my Post view:

```
<h6><a href="./#/">Back</a></h6>

<h1>POST ID: {{ currentPost.id }}</h1>
<h2>Name: {{ currentPost.name }}</h2>
<h3>Content: {{ currentPost.content }}</h3>
```

I'm not getting the values when the post view is loaded.

Thanks!

Comment: include the id of each post and use that in the url

Comment: Ok, but how to route and scope it in my controller?

Comment: Don't understand what you are asking. Don't copy new parts to question from answers when you don't have `id` in the data to begin with

Comment: Just putting the {{ post.id }} in my href parameter will do not load the correct object from my json array when I load the view.

Comment: If all the data is always in one file you need to iterate the array to find the matching id based on `$routeParams`

Comment: Just made a plnkr about that. I think its gonna help: http://plnkr.co/edit/brWn6r4UvLnNY5gcFF2X?p=preview

Comment: You had lots of issues in that demo. http://plnkr.co/edit/3BYSU4eA9v6ZDRNyFAjK?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix it with this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $route, $routeParams, $filter) {
  $scope.name = 'Test';

  $scope.getData = function(){
    $http.get('posts.json')
      .then(function(res){
          $scope.posts = res.data.posts;
          $scope.currentPost = $filter('filter')($scope.posts, {id: $routeParams.id});
          $scope.currentPost = $scope.currentPost[0]; // $filter apparently returns an array...
        });
  };
  setInterval($scope.getData, 1000);

  $scope.getData();

});
```

Plnkr updated: http://plnkr.co/edit/brWn6r4UvLnNY5gcFF2X?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

1st place you should add some identifier like `id` property on each post, so that while navigating to that post you could have that `id` in `URL` & then use `ng-href` with `interpolation` to form navigation URL

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts>
  <a ng-href="/post/{{post.id}}" >
   <h1>{{ post.name }}</h1>
   <h1>{{ post.content }}</h1>
  </a>
</div>
```

**Edit**

For showing post on the post page, you can take that parameter from `URL` using `$routeParams` service & then make filter on the received data then show it on HTML.

```
app.controller( 'PostsController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $filter) {
      $scope.getData = function(){
          $http.get('json/posts.json')
          .then(function(res){
              //for sec of simplicity you could add this data in service.
              $scope.posts = res.data.posts;
              $scope.currentPost = $filter('filter')($scope.posts, {id: $routeParams.id});
            });
      };
      $scope.getData(); //init
});
```

**views/post.html**

```
<div>
  <div> Post with id {{currentPost.id}}</div>
  <div> Name: {{currentPost.name}}</div>
  <div> Content: {{currentPost.content}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi!, Thanks! I did that, But how can I scope it to load the single content in another view?

Comment: Did not work, I think it was because my provided json has no id parameter at json object array. I could generate it from my controller?

Comment: @FernandoAureliano you should add that in your `.json` file as my first part of answer does already mentioned that part..

Comment: Yeah, But I cant do that because the json file is provided by another server who generate it, not I. =(

Comment: I just put the id manually in my local json test file to test the navigation. Like you say, the link works, but when the view is loaded, all its loaded is the {{currentPost.name}} and the others parameters. This view has been loaded inside the same controller that the list of posts.